# How compiling wxwidgets app staticaly?

Tags: c++, static, wxwidgets

I compiling my program in normal way.

```
mkdir mystatic

cd mystatic

make

g++ `./wx-config --static=yes --libs` `./wx-config --static=yes --cxxflags` etc
```

but when I type

```
ldd application I get many library.
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb76e7000)
    libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xb724b000)
    libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xb719d000)
    libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0xb718f000)
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 
....
```

How compiling my app staticaly. My app will be run on any Linux distribution.

Comment: try to set `-static` to `cflags` it will statically link all required library into single executable file

Comment: $g++ -static -O3 -Wall `wx-config --static=yes --libs` `wx-config --static=yes --cxxflags` test.o showbuff.o -o test-static
         /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latk-1.0
         /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
         collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
         make: *** [test-static] Błąd 1

Comment: In function `wxDynamicLibrary::GetProgramHandle()':
dlunix.cpp:(.text+0x13): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.a(libgio_2_0_la-glocalfileinfo.o): In function `lookup_gid_name':
(.text+0xf4c): warning: Using 'getgrgid_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking

Answer (score 2):

At first I have reinstalled wxWdgets from sources (http://wxwidgets.org/downloads/) (like here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=937810):

> ./configure --enable-optimise --enable-stl --enable-unicode --enable-threads --enable-static --disable-shared --enable-monolithic --enable-graphics_ctx --with-x11

```
make
make install
update-alternatives --config wx-config
updatedb
locate wx_ | sed '/doc/d;/\/usr\/l/d'
```

To make wxWidgets-2.8.12/samples/minimal

I have modified 'Makefile' LIBS string:

```
LIBS = -lz -ldl -lm -lX11 -lcairo
```

Than command `make`

And I have got executable file "minimal" of 3164131 bytes

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't link `libc` statically and in many cases you will have trouble with linking GTK+ libraries statically too (notice that this also has licensing implications). Instead, build the program on the oldest system you want to support (typically some ancient CentOS version), this works rather well in practice as all the other systems will have later, but compatible, versions of the libraries your program is linked with.